# Cilium Cluster Mesh unable to connect Clusters

Tags: kubernetes, networking, cilium

I have two clusters on GCP as shown below :[image]

I followed the tutorial : https://docs.cilium.io/en/v1.12/gettingstarted/clustermesh/clustermesh/

In order to install cilium in each cluster the following commands where used :

“cilium install –cluster-name clust2 –cluster-id 2”

“cilium install –cluster-name clust1 –cluster-id 1”

For the configuration of cluster mesh the following configurations where used :

[image]

When i try to connect the cluster i get “Unable to derive service IPs automatically”.

[image]

The status of the cluster mesh on each cluster is the same :
[image]

Any ideas/tips on how to debug this ?

Comment: Can you Post the output of these commands :
< cilium clustermesh status --context clust1 --wait >

and also check  Load Balancer status by using this command   < cilium service list >

Comment: ' cilium clustermesh status --context clust1 --wait " gives the same outpus, which is "Unable  to derive service IPs automatically", and for the second command there is no option "service" for cilium, thes output is "unkown command service for cilium"

Comment: As you are saying that second command there is no option "service" for cilium, thes output is "unkown command service for cilium" might be Load Balancer service is not created, might be the reason for Unable to derive service IPs automatically”.

Comment: hmm, i will to get to the bottom of this, thx for the help.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: no, i tried to use another cluster connection tool (etc Submariner).

Answer (score 0):

See cilium clustermesh-apiserver service it may be in pending status waiting loadbalancer external ip address.